# Alias not recognized in main script

Tags: qlikview

In the following code I've loaded data from two excel documents that have the exact same column names, and have therefore given one of the tables aliases.

My problem occurs when I try to put in a `not match()` condition at the end of the script.

```
// New table
NewTable:
LOAD 
    [namn] as namnNy
FROM
[pglistaNy.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels);

// Old table
OldTable:
LOAD 
    [namn]
FROM
[pglistaOld.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels)

Where not match(namn, namnNy);
```

I get an error telling me that it does not recognize the `namnNy` alias, why is that and what's a better solution / method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` function will not work in your case. You are trying to match values from field names from different tables. You should use the `exists` function (full documentation on Qlik's [help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2017/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Exists.htm))

So your script will be:

```
// New table
NewTable:
LOAD 
    [namn] as namnNy
FROM
[pglistaNy.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels);

// Old table
OldTable:
LOAD 
    [namn]
FROM
[pglistaOld.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels)    
Where 
  not Exists(namnNy, namn);
```

Example qvw file [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yFkvN0RXny1BJDfw5m72R7UyUY-JJn83)